# Generar una lista html con una función php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array, script, function

La función genera un menu al estilo arbol (ul li, etc.) extrayendo los valores de mysql:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
$data[$row->ParentId][] = $row;
}

function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0) {
static $i = 1;
//$tab = str_repeat('-', $i);
if ($data[$parent]) {
    $html .= "\n<ul" . ($parent == 0 ? ' class="tree"' : '') . ">\n";
    $i++;
    foreach ($data[$parent] as $v) {
        $child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent);
        $html .= "<li>";
        $html .= '<span onmouseover="this.title=this.innerText">' . $v->Title . "</span>";
        if ($child) {
            $i–;
            $html .= $child;
        }
        $html .= "</li>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>\n";
    return $html;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

echo (BuildTree($data));
```

el resultado seria algo como:

```
categoria A<br>
-subcategoria de categoria A<br>
--sub categoria A de sub categoria A<br>
categoria B<br>
....y asi sucesivamente....
```

Todo funciona bien, pero lo que no logro hacer, es obtener las llaves de cada uno de los elementos del array como si de un breadcrumbs se tratara:

```
categoria A [0]<br>
-subcategoria de categoria A [00]<br>
--sub categoria A de sub categoria A [000]<br>
--sub categoria B de sub categoria A [001]<br>
categoria B [1]<br>
....y asi sucesivamente....
```

Llevo buscando hace varios dias y ha llegado un momento en el cual estoy bloqueado, he encontrado una funcion que obtiene las llaves de cada elemento, pero no puedo combinar dichas funciones.

La función es la siguiente:

```
function GetKeys($array, $tree = array()) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        GetKeys($value, array_merge($tree, array($key)));
    } else {
        print implode('.', array_merge($tree, array($key, $value)));
        print "\n<br />";
    }
}
}

GetKeys($data);
```

El resultado del array ($data) con los datos obtenidos de la db es el siguiente:

adjunto la imagen var_dump($data) porque no se como pegar el resultado formateado:

[image: resultado array]

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `tree` (
`Parent` int(16) NOT NULL,
`ParentId` int(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`CategoryWriteDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`LastMod` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Por otro lado, el primer paso para resolver el problema es obtener las _llaves_, en el primer código tienes un _foreach_, cambialo a `foreach ($data[$parent] as $key => $v) {`, así obtendrás las llaves de cada nodo en `$key`, luego ¿En que parte quieres mostrar tus _llaves_?

Comment: las llaves deberian mostrarse dentro de cada etiqueda <li> en un tag llamado path="" que variaria infinitamente dependiendo de la profundidad de cada elemento, por ej x.x.x.x seria una concatenacion de todas las llaves correspondiente a cada elemento mostrado dentro de (x) elemento como un breadcrumbs pero solo conformado de llaves

Comment: he cambiado lo del foreach, ahora en var_dump() muestra las llaves independientes, lo q tendria q hacer seria concatenarlas en cada iteracion

Comment: Entonces cambia `function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0) {` por `function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0, $k=false) {`, luego cambia `$child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent);` por `$child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent, $k.$key);` y luego `$html .= "<li>";` por `$html .= "<li path='".$k.$key"'>";` y me cuentas que tal te fue.

Comment: realmente has echo que vuelva a sonreir! funciono, incluso ya no es necesaria la funcion GetKey(), te doy gracias! la verdad me quede sorprendido, a practicar mas se ha dicho!

Comment: De nada, antes déjame colocar los comentarios en una respuesta antes de que un moderador lo sugiera.

Answer (score 2):

El primer paso para resolver el problema es obtener las llaves, en el primer código tienes un *foreach*, cambialo a `foreach ($data[$parent] as $key => $v) {`, así obtendrás las llaves de cada nodo en `$key`, luego cambia `function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0) {` por `function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0, $k=false) {`, `$child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent);` por `$child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent, $k.$key);` y por ultimo `$html .= "<li>";` por `$html .= "<li path='".$k.$key"'>";`.

En resumen el código queda de esta forma:

```
function BuildTree($data, $parent = 0, $k=false) {
static $i = 1;
if ($data[$parent]) {
$html .= "\n<ul" . ($parent == 0 ? ' class="tree"' : '') . ">\n";
$i++;
foreach ($data[$parent] as $key => $v) {
    $child = BuildTree($data, $v->Parent, $k.$key);
    $html .= "<li>[" . $k.$key . ']';
    $html .= '<span>' . $v->Title . "</span>";
    if ($child) {
        $i–;
        $html .= $child;
    }
    $html .= "</li>\n";
}
$html .= "</ul>\n";
return $html;
} else {
return false;
}
}

echo (BuildTree($data));
```

Me da gusto que haya sido de ayuda. Saludos.